# JSON to JSON transformations with .NET

Tags: .net, json, xslt, transform

I am trying to find a standard way of transforming JSON contents to JSON while applying transformations, in a similar way to what XSLT does for XML. To my surprise, couldn't find any standard for this, only some half baked implementations.
What is the generally accepted way of doing this? Could it be, for example, turning JSON into XML, applying XSLT, and then converting back to JSON?

Comment: perhaps jsonpatch could be an answer : http://jsonpatch.com/.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: I started writing a library in .net that applies operations to a json document  and give you a transformed json back (not real jsonpatch as I am using jsonpath instead of jsonpointer now) : still in dev : https://github.com/CedricDumont/CExtensions-Patch

Comment: Interesting, will have a look!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this, which could possibly be ported to .NET without too much effort &/or may inspire you:

https://jsfiddle.net/YSharpLanguage/kj9pk8oz/10

Example of use, taking its inspiration from https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Document-Example:

```
/*
  Cf. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Document-Example
*/
var D1document = {
    type: "document", title: [ "Document Title" ],
    "": [
      { type: "chapter", title: [ "Chapter Title" ],
        "": [
        { type: "section", title: [ "Section Title" ],
          "": [
            { type: "para", "": [ "This is a test." ] },
            { type: "note", "": [ "This is a note." ] }
        ] },
        { type: "section", title: [ "Another Section Title" ],
          "": [
            { type: "para", "": [ "This is ", { emph: "another" }, " test." ] },
            { type: "note", "": [ "This is another note." ] }
        ] }
      ] }
    ] };

var D1toHTML = { $: [
  [ [ function(node) { return node.type === "document"; } ],
    function(root) {
      return "<html>\r\n\
  <head>\r\n\
    <title>\r\n\
      {title}\r\n".of(root) + "\
    </title>\r\n\
  </head>\r\n\
  <body>\r\n\
{*}".of(root[""].through(this)) + "\
  </body>\r\n\
</html>";
    }
  ],
  [ [ function(node) { return node.type === "chapter"; } ],
    function(chapter) {
      return "    <h2>{title}</h2>\r\n".of(chapter) + "{*}".of(chapter[""].through(this));
    }
  ],
  [ [ function(node) { return node.type === "section"; } ],
    function(section) {
      return "    <h3>{title}</h3>\r\n".of(section) + "{*}".of(section[""].through(this));
    }
  ],
  [ [ function(node) { return node.type === "para"; } ],
    function(para) {
      return "    <p>{*}</p>\r\n".of(para[""].through(this));
    }
  ],
  [ [ function(node) { return node.type === "note"; } ],
    function(note) {
      return '    <p class="note"><b>NOTE: </b>{*}</p>\r\n'.of(note[""].through(this));
    }
  ],
  [ [ function(node) { return node.emph; } ],
    function(emph) {
      return "<em>{emph}</em>".of(emph);
    }
  ]
] };

console.log(D1document.through(D1toHTML));
```

... which gives:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Document Title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Chapter Title</h2>
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <p>This is a test.</p>
    <p class="note"><b>NOTE: </b>This is a note.</p>
    <h3>Another Section Title</h3>
    <p>This is <em>another</em> test.</p>
    <p class="note"><b>NOTE: </b>This is another note.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

... while the following (cf. https://jsfiddle.net/YSharpLanguage/ppfmmu15/10)

```
// (A "Company" is just an object with a "Team")
function Company(obj) {
  return obj.team && Team(obj.team);
}

// (A "Team" is just a non-empty array that contains at least one "Member")
function Team(obj) {
  return ({ }.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]") &&
         obj.length &&
         obj.find(function(item) { return Member(item); });
}

// (A "Member" must have first and last names, and a gender)
function Member(obj) {
  return obj.first && obj.last && obj.sex;
}

function Dude(obj) {
  return Member(obj) && (obj.sex === "Male");
}

function Girl(obj) {
  return Member(obj) && (obj.sex === "Female");
}

var data = { team: [
  { first: "John", last: "Smith", sex: "Male" },
  { first: "Vaio", last: "Sony" },
  { first: "Anna", last: "Smith", sex: "Female" },
  { first: "Peter", last: "Olsen", sex: "Male" }
] };

var TO_SOMETHING_ELSE = { $: [

  [ [ Company ],
    function(company) {
      return { some_virtual_dom: {
        the_dudes: { ul: company.team.select(Dude).through(this) },
        the_grrls: { ul: company.team.select(Girl).through(this) }
      } }
    } ],

  [ [ Member ],
    function(member) {
      return { li: "{first} {last} ({sex})".of(member) };
    } ]

] };

console.log(JSON.stringify(data.through(TO_SOMETHING_ELSE), null, 4));
```

... will give you:

```
{
    "some_virtual_dom": {
        "the_dudes": {
            "ul": [
                {
                    "li": "John Smith (Male)"
                },
                {
                    "li": "Peter Olsen (Male)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "the_grrls": {
            "ul": [
                {
                    "li": "Anna Smith (Female)"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

'Hope this helps,